код с использованием omp parallel работает медленнее
почему параллельное сложение векторов работает медленнее последовательного?
int i;
start_time1 = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for shared(a, b, c) private(i)
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
run_time1 = omp_get_wtime() - start_time1;

start_time2 = omp_get_wtime();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

run_time2 = omp_get_wtime() - start_time2;


Наверное n слишком мало

@avp n беру по 1000-10000

Посмотрите, что получится при 10000000 (десять миллионов)

@avp, действительно, для большего n параллельный вариант быстрее, спасибо!

Если вместо сложения будет достаточно сложная функция, то эффект будет заметен и на меньшем размере массива. Определяющим фактором для простой вычислительной функции является скорость доступа к памяти. А при малых n  все массивы попадают в кэш (время доступа к нему маленькое) и поэтому за время создания нового потока все вычисления уже будут проведены в первом (уже существующем main). Для более подробного анализа надо смотреть ассемблерный код программы и конкретную конфигурацию компьютера на котором вы запускаете тест
